# Solving exercise 1.6.1 in katznelson's book

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I need to show that:
 for $n=1,2,...$  if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T}) $ with $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}_n(k)| \leq 1$ for every $n$ and if $f_n$ converges uniformly to f on $\mathbb{T}$, then $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(k)|\leq 1.$

My attempt:

Since $f_n$ converges to f  uniformly on the circle, we know $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} s.t. \forall x \in \mathbb{T}$ and $\forall n \geq N, |f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \epsilon.$

This implies $|\hat{f}(k)-\hat{f}_n(k)|\leq \epsilon $ $ \forall |n|\geq N$

Thus,

$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(k)|= \sum_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(k)- \hat{f}_n(k)+\hat{f}_n(k)|\leq 1+ \epsilon \sum_{-\infty}^\infty1$

This does not seem useful for my problem...

Comment: This is correct but you have just proved that $\sum |\widehat f (k) | \le +\infty$ which is always correct

Comment: I know.  But it is useless for my problem.

Comment: Perhaps you have to change $\forall |k| \ge N$ by $\forall n \ge N$

Comment: You are right. Question edited. I am still stuck with an infinite sum however... @Youem

Comment: Take $\epsilon_k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $\widehat{f_{n}}(k)\rightarrow\widehat{f}(k)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, for each $k$, then Fatou's Lemma gives
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}|\widehat{f}(k)|&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\widehat{f_{n}}(k)|\\
&\leq\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}|\widehat{f_{n}}(k)|\\
&\leq\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}1\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: If you do not want to use Fatou. Let $K \in \mathbb N$ and you have $$\sum_{k=-K}^{K}|\widehat{f}(k)| = \sum_{k=-K}^{K}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\widehat{f_{n}}(k)| = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=-K}^K |\widehat{f_{n}}(k)| \le 1$$ Which is exaclty the same as using Fatou.

Comment: Very good, even more elementary.